# Does WinUI has an equivalent of UWP's .NET Native?

Tags: c#, compilation, native-code, winui-3, winui

UWP can generate native code using [.NET Native](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/dotnet-native/), is there an equivalent for WinUI?

Comment: .net core has `dotnet build` which will target native directly if you ask. For .net framwerok there is ngen

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, this option appears to have been removed from it, can you elaborate?

Comment: my bad - dotnet publish

Comment: ie `dotnet publish --runtime osx.10.11-x64`

Comment: Okay I think I've got it now, it's called ReadyToRun: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish#msbuild

Comment: @aybe, if you have a satisfactory answer to your question, I think it'd be helpful for future visitors if you supply a self-answer to your question.

Comment: Yes, I still need to try that out to confirm that indeed it works.

Comment: Doesn't dotnet publish just generate executables that essentially contain a copy of the .NET runtime that would then load your program and JIT it (or use a pre compiled start of your app to increase start up time). .NET Native on the other hand generates native code and doesn't use JIT to run your app

Comment: I have no idea to be honest.